# Which one is better object or top function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I put some utility in Tool.kt, Both Method A and Method B can work well.

I think Method B will keep in memory when I start an app even if I never invoke `fun <T> preference(context: Context, name: String,   default: T)`

I think Method A only allocate memory when I invoke `DelegatesExt.preference(this,"ZipCode",100L)`

So I think Method A is the better than  Method B, right?

**Method A**

```
object DelegatesExt {
   fun <T> preference(context: Context, name: String,   default: T) = Preference(context, name, default)
}


class Preference<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String,
        private val default: T) {

    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        context.getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = findPreference(name, default)

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }

        res as T
    }

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

**Method B**

```
fun <T> preference(context: Context, name: String,   default: T) = Preference(context, name, default)



class Preference<T>(private val context: Context, private val name: String,
        private val default: T) {

    private val prefs: SharedPreferences by lazy {
        context.getSharedPreferences("default", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = findPreference(name, default)

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        putPreference(name, value)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    private fun findPreference(name: String, default: T): T = with(prefs) {
        val res: Any = when (default) {
            is Long -> getLong(name, default)
            is String -> getString(name, default)
            is Int -> getInt(name, default)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(name, default)
            is Float -> getFloat(name, default)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can be saved into Preferences")
        }

        res as T
    }

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    private fun putPreference(name: String, value: T) = with(prefs.edit()) {
        when (value) {
            is Long -> putLong(name, value)
            is String -> putString(name, value)
            is Int -> putInt(name, value)
            is Boolean -> putBoolean(name, value)
            is Float -> putFloat(name, value)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This type can't be saved into Preferences")
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method A** will allocate `object DelegatesExt` during static class initialization - as soon as you reference `DelegatesExt` in your code, because `object` in Kotlin is singleton with lazy initialization.

Then, when you'll call `DelegatesExt.preference(...)`, it will allocate your `Preference<T>` object. By the way, it will allocate a new instance on each call, which is not a good idea.

Then, when you'll call either `getValue` or `setValue`, `SharedPreferences` will be allocated (once only per `Preference<T>` instance).

**Method B** doesn't allocate a redundant `object DelegatesExt`, and `Preference<T>` will be allocated on each method call as well.
This will be compiled to effectively the same code as a class with a static method in Java.

But `Preference<T>` won't be allocated before a `preference` method call (in both cases).

Long story short, both options are almost the same, except of the `object DelegatesExt` being allocated or not. But it's worth to stop allocating a new `Preference<T>` on each `preference` method call.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that both options are almost the same? I can choose any one!

Comment: Yes, they are almost the same. Method B is tiny bit better IMO, but the difference is very subtle and not important.

Answer (score 1):

> I think Method B will keep in memeory when I start a app even if I never invoke `fun <T> preference(context: Context, name: String,   default: T)`

1. What exactly would it keep in memory?
2. No, the methods are the same except for use when invoking in Kotlin. But in fact, the method B `preference` is inside class `ToolKt` which you can see if you try to call it from Java.
3. Why define either of the `preference` functions instead of using `Preference` constructor directly? Kotlin constructors don't have issues with type inference like Java's do.